# Where is Firefox' DNS cache stored on Fedora 31?

Tags: fedora, dns, firefox, cache

I would like to programmatically clear Firefox' DNS cache from a script. Where is Firefox' DNS cache stored in Fedora 31?

Comment: The right question is surely _How do I clear firefox's DNS cache on version NNN of firefox?_, as at https://superuser.com/q/747587/38062 , because "inside firefox" is not going to get you very far.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP that seems like it'd be my answer (even doesn't really help). What do you reckon I should do about this question?